# How to handle Default app crashing when starting

Tags: raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core, dragonboard

I am currently developing an application that we intend to be able to run on Windows 10 IoT Core.

Twice during the development cycle, I've faced a scenario where the app would either crash during initialization, or would fail to start due to a dependency not being there such as `Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0.appx`

For a desktop computer app, this is usually easy to correct, but when it's on the IoT device, and If I have it set to be the default app, the device will reboot after each crash.

Because of this, I have a frame of about 1 second where I can connect to the device and attempt to set the Default app to something else, so I can stabilize it.  It is quite difficult to do this in the time frame.  I've had to re-flash these devices before.

It's at its worst when I'm running it on a dragonboard 410c, but I also run it on a Rasperry Pi 2, and have observed the same issue.

Is there a way to stabilize the device without re-flashing it?

Comment: Are you debugging using Visual Studio or installing the application?

Comment: Or checked the error reports in the [Windows Device Portal](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/tools/deviceportal)?

Comment: @IanHoppes  I'm installing the application without the debugger

Comment: As for checking the error reports, I'll have to get back to you on that on Monday.  I'm out of town for the weekend,

Comment: @IanHoppes  Sorry for the late reply.  It seems as though, at least right now, just putting `Task.Delay(5000).Wait(); 
throw new Exception("test");`  doesn't cause the whole device to crash repeatedly like I was seeing before.  If I see this behavior again, I'll come back and let you know what's in the error report